# Delete products function - NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do the 'Delete products' function by using Node.JS but I just don't know where I am wrong. I hope you can spend a few minutes to look at my code and give me your solution. Thank you in advance!

```
// NodeJS code
router.get('/remove-posts', async function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    let dbo = client.db("HomeFitness");
    await dbo.collection("posts").deleteOne({ _id: ObjectID(id) });
    res.redirect("statistics-posts");
});

// HTML code
<a href="/remove-posts/{{_id}}">
   <button type="submit" class="custom-btn btn-7" ><span>Remove</span></button>  
</a>
```

Comment: When you are passing the id of the product you want to delete.

Comment: @JeevanSrivastava I have just updated. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing id in params and fetching in body. thus your are getting undefined.

// NodeJS code

```
router.get('/remove-posts/:id', async function(req, res, next) {
    const { params:{ id } } = req;
    const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    let dbo = client.db("HomeFitness");
    await dbo.collection("posts").deleteOne({ _id: ObjectID(id) });
    res.redirect("statistics-posts");
});
```